# I'm looking for a Gigabyte Smile

Tags: media, picture-import-wizard

I'm a film producer and I have in my possesion a 7.31-Gigabyte compressed file of raw footage.  I currently have the file stored in my g-mail account comfortably. I have tried to extract the file(BDMV.zip) on public library computer and college systems and it would not avail. I also stored it on DropBox, I'm not sure what Extractor to use. My primary objective is to decompress and download the individual footage frames(about 9) onto appropriate storage device(flash-card,ect.) Can you help?

Comment: ZIP only supports up to about 4GB (both for the size of the zip and any files it is archiving) due to 32-bit number representations. There is such a thing as "ZIP64" which supports larger file sizes, but I do not think Windows' built-in ZIP libraries support ZIP64. I don't know any more about than this, otherwise I would make a full answer. Just be careful about which utility you choose. Look for a reputable (open source) zip 64 implementation if you can. Also be prepared to have at least 2-3x the disk space available for the unzipped files.

Comment: Note for next time that video really cannot be compressed by any 'zip' type algorithm, so whoever/however it was sent to you, please ask them not to do it again & you can skip this step next time. Also consider using something like https://www.wetransfer.com to send large files rather than any type of email.

Answer (score 1):

I second those who say you should do this on your own computer, not a shared computer. The requirements size-wise and software-wise put it beyond the scope of default Windows capability.

That said, on your own computer you can install any of several 3rd party compression utilities which do excellent jobs decompressing very large files.

Personally, I use 7zip and use it a lot. It's fast, simple, and it handles just about any compression method I'm aware of.

Answer (score -1):

Judging your computer skills from what You have posted I think that best bet would be for You to just download the whole zipped file onto Your computer and extracting it there.
Extracting such a big file on library computers might be impossible due to limitations that exist on such systems, not allowing users to exceed couple GB storage, which Your raw zipped footage + unzipped footage clearly exceeds.

For extracting You can use 7zip.
http://www.7-zip.org/
Choose the x64 version, if it doesn't work try the x32.